# Pass types to a method and return property values

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I am trying to cut down code when reading data from an API. I have a lot of very similar methods, and I'm sure I can refactor them to one, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Below is a very simplified version of code -

I want to refactot the "ReturnManagerName" and "ReturnTrainerName" into one method, can someone help?

```
void Main()
{
  Team team = new Team();

  Manager manager = new Manager();
  manager.ManagerName = "Mr Manager";

  team.TeamManager = manager;

  Console.WriteLine ("Manager: " + ReturnManagerName(team));
  Console.WriteLine ("Trainer: " + ReturnTrainerName(team));
}

string ReturnManagerName(Team team)
{
  if(team.TeamManager == null)
    return "None";
  return team.TeamManager.ManagerName;
}

string ReturnTrainerName(Team team)
{
  if(team.TeamTrainer == null)
    return "None";
  return team.TeamTrainer.TrainerName;
}

public class Team
{
  public Manager TeamManager { get; set; }
  public Trainer TeamTrainer { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
  public string ManagerName { get; set; }
}

public class Trainer
{
  public string TrainerName { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using reflection with some thing like.

```
string ReturnTeamMemberName(object manager, string propName)
{
   if(manager == null)
      return "None";      
   return manager.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(manager, null).ToString();
}
```

Call it like,

```
Console.WriteLine ("Manager: " + ReturnTeamMemberName(team.TeamManager, "ManagerName"));
Console.WriteLine ("Trainer: " + ReturnTeamMemberName(team.TeamTrainer,"TrainerName" ));
```

Comment: He's not retrieving a `Team`'s property, he's retrieving either a `TeamManager` or a `TeamTrainer`'s property

Comment: Brilliant, thats exactly what I want - as the issue extends to about 20 or so properties. Thank you - just need to change object manager, to object member to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Updated as per comment:

```
public class Person 
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Team
{
    public Person Manager { get; set; }
    public Person Trainer { get; set; }
}

public class PrettyPrinter
{
    public string GetNameOrNone(Person p)
    {
        return p != null ? p.Name : "None";
    }

}
```

and then in Main:

```
{
    Team team = new Team();

    team.Manager = new Person("Mr. Manager");

    PrettyPrinter p = new PrettyPrinter();

    Console.WriteLine ("Manager: " + p.GetNameOrNone(team.Manager));
    Console.WriteLine ("Trainer: " + p.GetNameOrNone(team.Trainer));
}
```

Comment: I would use this, but the example is for ilustration only. The data get serialised from an API for which I use s class generator as the data set returned is huge. There could for example be another class Stadium with properties Length and Width, where I would want to check to see if Stadium was null before returning "none" if it didn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Wilbert, but as I regularly get API updates, I can't mess with the class heirarchy - I need to work with the structure I have. Adil has given me the workable solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this:

```
Tuple<string,string> ReturnNames(Team team)
{
  var trainerName = (team.TeamTrainer == null)? "None" : team.TeamTrainer.TrainerName;
  var managerName = (team.TeamTrainer == null)? "None" : team.TeamManager.ManagerName;
  return Tuple.Create(trainerName, managerName);
}

var tuple = ReturnNames(team);
Console.WriteLine ("Manager: " + tuple.Item1 );
Console.WriteLine ("Trainer: " + tuple.Item2 );
```

But does this really buy you anything? It seems you'll only be adding complexity to something that is perfectly readable as it is.

Comment: That's a bad idea - a person can have different roles, and roles can change. Inheritance should not be used here. Better to have a Person assigned to the manager role.

Comment: That depends on his requirements. You're right, if the roles will change at runtime, then he should favor composition over inheritance. I'll remove my "side note".